# Rebus #25 needs your scrutiny

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, rebus

Some animals are more clever than others...

1-word singular noun

[image]

---

Here's a clue for part of a famous example of the rebus image:

[image]

Comment: First thought: invisible crocodile tears

Comment: Sorry, no cigar.

Comment: Now I have ZZ Top’s “Sharp Dressed Man” stuck in my head.

Comment: Except that would have the picture of a man. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I really hope it's an...

> In-vest-igator?!

The hint is

> **Shir**ring, as a reference to a famous investigator Sherlock Holmes.

Comment: YYYYYes!  You got it.

Comment: haha and I thought the answer was just 'crocs' footwear... :)

Comment: can you explain the close up picture of fabric? How does that connect?

Comment: @KateGregory:  it's an example of shirring.  The first half of the word is the clue.

Comment: And what does shirring have to do with the answer? To me it's a random un-needed part of the question and you're ignoring it too. If you used it in some way, can you explain it?

Comment: @Kate Gregory - hope that helps.  I submitted my answer before the image was edited in, so I didn't use it to solve.

Comment: @Reibello:  Super!   Your adding that to your answer keeps me from having to spill the beans.  {thumbs up}